# Are there any statistics on how often a search in the Help Center ends in "0 Results"

Tags: support, search, help-center

I saw an [MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386321/578411) (10k only) where the user tried to search for their issue in the Help center.

Their search term didn't return any results which shows them this page:

[image]

Before I'm proposing a feature request in this area I would like to know how many of the Help Center searches end in "0 Results" and if possible a top 10 or so of search terms that were tried and didn't return results. Network wide is fine.

Are these statistics somewhat convenient available and if so, can these be posted as an answer?

Comment: The help center search is actually pretty terrible because it doesn’t take things like plurals/verb forms into account.  “upvote” and “upvotes” return a different number of results.

Comment: Yeah, true. I wasn't going to suggest an overhaul as that is not going to happen 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @Laurel also, it's terrible with languages with multiple cases and word endings (e.g. Russian) T_T

Comment: _No help pages match your search "logout". Did you mean [how to exit vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-do-i-exit-the-vim-editor)_