# Where can I find examples of Stack Exchange search queries?

Tags: discussion, search, data-dump, data-analysis, research

Is there a dataset available to the research community that contains example queries for Stack Exchange results related to sotware? **By search queries I mean "pandas to_csv tab delimiter" and not a SQL query the Stack Exchange data dump.**

Stack Overflow would be ideal but any code-related site would be great. This would be a powerful dataset to enable researchers to figure out what people are searching about to drive research into better code search relevance.

Stack Exchange has been amazing about sharing its data, but I can't find any query datasets it has published. Is this something Stack Exchange has done, or is planning to do in the future? Where can I find any existing datasets with code search queries?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean this: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries ? Did you see this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data and https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2020

Comment: @rene I've looked all over including those links and there is nothing on search queries for code solutions. I've edited the question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: That is not publicly available and I wonder if it is easily producible  for an SE dev. It might require a parse of the log files.

Comment: Any real data would have to be sanitized before it could be released publicly, or you would have to do a NDA.

Comment: @Laurel queries wouldn't be tied to users so I don't think there would be a privacy problem. Releasing only frequent queries would do a lot of sanitization, and these are the most useful anyway.

Comment: @rene It would require parsing logs, but these are probably stored in a way that is easy to access and process because they will already be used to optimize search.

Comment: @user147894 it is probably so easy that an earlier slightly related [question of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329901/158100) is still unanswered after 6 to 8 weeks.